# Sudo command discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot sudo command but im not sure how to make the person send the message.
The command would be like this:

> ">sudo @user#tag message"

and then the person you mentioned would say the message.

Ive tried this:

```
async def sudo(ctx, user, *, message):
    await user.ctx.send(f'{message}')
```

I also tried

```
async def sudo(ctx, user, *, message):
    await ctx.user.send(f'{message}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define your `user` in order to send the message.

***Reformat your code to the following:***

```py
@client.command() / @bot.command() / @commands.command()
async def sudo(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, message): # added discord.Member
    await user.send(f"{message}")
```

Comment: it just sends a dm to the person, not sudo's them to say something.

Comment: What exactly do you want them to do then? You can't mention someone and then the account of the user says what you inserted into the command?

Comment: This is connected to getting access to the user account. What I provided is a simple DM-command which should only be accessable to you as the bot owner.